# How can I remove some keys from a JSON string where the values are preventing me from parsing it as JSON?

Tags: json, regex

I have this string coming in from a HTTP request:

```
s = "{'id': 81, 'udate': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 3, 7, 20, 5, 369376, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), 'cdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 11, 9, 50, 0, 984521, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), 'screen_name': 'Hellas Utrecht', 'follower_id': '310489102', 'is_unfollow': True, 'user_id': 8, 'follower_description': 'Atletiekvereniging Hellas Utrecht heeft zo’n 1600 leden, verdeeld over de afd. jeugd-, weg- en baanatletiek, recreatie en triathlon.', 'follower_favourites_count': '675', 'follower_followers_count': '741', 'follower_listed_count': '9', 'follower_location': 'Utrecht', 'follower_screen_name': 'HellasUtrecht', 'follower_statuses_count': '904'}"
```

I need to convert it to a dictionary but the keys `udate` and `cdate` are preventing me from doing so as they are in the form of a function i.e. `datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 3, 7, 20, 5, 369376, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))` which throws an error `malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x109346890>`.

Currently my solution is to just manually convert the string to a dictionary by excluding the strings by indexing(but this excludes the `id`):

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval('{'+s[250:])
>>>{'screen_name': 'Hellas Utrecht', 'follower_id': '310489102', 'is_unfollow': True, 'user_id': 8, 'follower_description': 'Atletiekvereniging Hellas Utrecht heeft zo’n 1600 leden, verdeeld over de afd. jeugd-, weg- en baanatletiek, recreatie en triathlon.', 'follower_favourites_count': '675', 'follower_followers_count': '741', 'follower_listed_count': '9', 'follower_location': 'Utrecht', 'follower_screen_name': 'HellasUtrecht', 'follower_statuses_count': '904'}
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to do so using regex? I just need the keys `udate`,`cdate` and their values to be removed.

Expected output:

```
"{'id': 81, 'screen_name': 'Hellas Utrecht', 'follower_id': '310489102', 'is_unfollow': True, 'user_id': 8, 'follower_description': 'Atletiekvereniging Hellas Utrecht heeft zo’n 1600 leden, verdeeld over de afd. jeugd-, weg- en baanatletiek, recreatie en triathlon.', 'follower_favourites_count': '675', 'follower_followers_count': '741', 'follower_listed_count': '9', 'follower_location': 'Utrecht', 'follower_screen_name': 'HellasUtrecht', 'follower_statuses_count': '904'}"
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Convert `udate` and `cdate` items to datetime values as string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no I need them to be completely removed. I will add an expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just added the expected output.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/r1SuDG, remove the items with `'[uc]date':\s*datetime\.datetime\(\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*,\s*tzinfo=[\w.]+\([^()]*\)\)\s*,?` regex, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSzYgY/1). Or with `'[uc]date':\s*datetime\.datetime\([^()]+\([^()]*\)\)\s*,?` regex, see [this update](https://regex101.com/r/iSzYgY/2) (which is a bit more generic).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove these two keys with their values using

```py
s = re.sub(r"'[uc]date':\s*datetime\.datetime\([^()]+\([^()]*\)\)\s*,?", '', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSzYgY/2). *Details*:

- `'[uc]date':` - `'udate':` or `'cdate':`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `datetime\.datetime\(` - a `datetime.datetime(` string
- `[^()]+` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]+` - one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)\)` -  a `))` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `,?` - an optional comma.

Then, you may use `ast.literal_eval` on the result, see the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/r1SuDG):

```py
import re, ast
s = "{'id': 81, 'udate': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 3, 7, 20, 5, 369376, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), 'cdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 11, 9, 50, 0, 984521, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), 'screen_name': 'Hellas Utrecht', 'follower_id': '310489102', 'is_unfollow': True, 'user_id': 8, 'follower_description': 'Atletiekvereniging Hellas Utrecht heeft zo’n 1600 leden, verdeeld over de afd. jeugd-, weg- en baanatletiek, recreatie en triathlon.', 'follower_favourites_count': '675', 'follower_followers_count': '741', 'follower_listed_count': '9', 'follower_location': 'Utrecht', 'follower_screen_name': 'HellasUtrecht', 'follower_statuses_count': '904'}"
s = re.sub(r"'[uc]date':\s*datetime\.datetime\([^()]+\([^()]*\)\)\s*,?", '', s)
print( ast.literal_eval(s) )
=> {'id': 81, 'screen_name': 'Hellas Utrecht', 'follower_id': '310489102', 'is_unfollow': True, 'user_id': 8, 'follower_description': 'Atletiekvereniging Hellas Utrecht heeft zo’n 1600 leden, verdeeld over de afd. jeugd-, weg- en baanatletiek, recreatie en triathlon.', 'follower_favourites_count': '675', 'follower_followers_count': '741', 'follower_listed_count': '9', 'follower_location': 'Utrecht', 'follower_screen_name': 'HellasUtrecht', 'follower_statuses_count': '904'}
```